# Where is Math.round() in Dart?

Tags: dart

I don't see any way to round a number in Dart?

```
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  print(Math.round(5.5)); // Error!
}
```

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_math.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. The [`num`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.5/dart-core/num-class.html) class has a method called [`round()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.5/dart-core/num/round.html):

```dart
var foo = 6.28;
print(foo.round()); // 6

var bar = -6.5;
print(bar.round()); // -7
```

Answer (score 11):

In Dart, everything is an object. So, when you declare a num, for example, you can round it through the [round method from the num class](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/num.html#round), the following code would print 6

```
num foo = 5.6;
print(foo.round()); //prints 6
```

In your case, you could do:

```
main() {
    print((5.5).round());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This equation will help you

```
int a = 500;
int b = 250;
int c;

c = a ~/ b;
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE March 2021:**

The `round()` method has moved to https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/num/round.html. All the above links are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help in specific situations, floor() will round towards the negative infinite

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/num/floor.html

```
void main() {
 var foo = 3.9;
 var bar = foo.floor();
 print(bar);//prints 3
}
```