# How to Double Parse A String and Round It to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the String values that are added from

```
List<String> priceStringList
```

and converted into Doubles to

```
List<double> doubleList
```

to only have 2 decimal places.

```
for (int j = 0; j < priceStringList.length; j++) {
          var doubleData = double.parse(priceStringList[j]);
          doubleList.add(doubleData);
        }
```

Sample data for doubleList after the for loop include:

```
[3.429, 3.44, 3.49, 3.41683, 3.35501, 3.02, 3.06, 3.17947,...
```

But I want the values to only include the first 2 digits after the decimal point. I tried using

```
      var doubleData = Math.Round(double.parse(priceStringList[j]), 2);
```

but I get an error stating "Undefined name 'Math'".

**EDIT** I have already added `import 'dart:math';`

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-math/dart-math-library.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Math.round() in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275824/where-is-math-round-in-dart)

Comment: @pskink I've already imported the math library

Comment: i mean `math` library does not have `round` method - `double` class has it

Comment: Have you tried toStringAsFixed()

Comment: I was gonna suggest importing math, but you could just do this, even though its longer. `var doubleData = double.parse(double.parse(priceStringList[j]).toStringAsFixed(2))`

Comment: @pskin so how would I round it to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @KetanRamteke I haven't tried that because I need a double value at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double roundDouble(double value, int places){ 
   double mod = pow(10.0, places); 
   return ((value * mod).round().toDouble() / mod); 
}

var doubleData = roundDouble(double.parse(priceStringList[j]), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To call `Math` you have to import it as `Math`, for example:

```
import 'dart:math' as Math;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).